# is this valid JSON? error: Content not allowed in prolog

Tags: json, parsing, basex

How do I test the below `JSON` files for correctness?

Using `basex` on the command line:

```
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ ls
formatted.json  raw.json
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> CREATE DATABASE db raw.json
"/home/thufir/json/raw.json" (Line 1): Content is not allowed in prolog.
> 
> CREATE DATABASE db formatted.json
"/home/thufir/json/formatted.json" (Line 1): Content is not allowed in prolog.
> 
> exit
Have fun.
thufir@dur:~/json$
```

I ran the raw data through a [formatter](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to make it more readable:

```
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ cat formatted.json 
{
  "1224083010015956992": {
    "metadata": {
      "result_type": "recent",
      "iso_language_code": "en"
    },
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "created_at": "Sun Feb 02 21:31:46 +0000 2020",
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "source": "<a href=\"https://mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web App<\/a>",
    "retweeted_status": {
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent",
        "iso_language_code": "en"
      },
      "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
      "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
      "created_at": "Sun Feb 02 20:53:32 +0000 2020",
      "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
      "source": "<a href=\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck<\/a>",
      "retweet_count": 3,
      "retweeted": false,
      "geo": null,
      "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
      "is_quote_status": false,
      "id_str": "1224073388706189312",
      "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
      "favorite_count": 6,
      "id": 1224073388706189312,
      "text": "Myth of the 10x programmer:\n\nh......... particularly like the list of productivity improvement \"tools\" at the end.",
      "place": null,
      "lang": "en",
      "favorited": false,
      "possibly_sensitive": false,
```

Given that the online parser shows the data and can explore nodes, can't see what the problem would be.

full:

https://gist.github.com/THUFIR/ab9e1f77af92d4d984b268434afc01dd.js

Comment: There is a great all-in-one JSON formatter and validator [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: thanks, it seems fine to me per that validator.  at least, didn't say any errors but displays the data.

Comment: Also I believe you added the wrong gist link to your question. Is [this](https://gist.github.com/THUFIR/ab9e1f77af92d4d984b268434afc01dd) what you meant?

Comment: "Content is not allowed in prolog" is an error for malformatted XML files; it's not an error for JSON files. I don't know basex but it looks like your database is interpreting the data as XML, not as json.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Good observation, especially so given that *"BaseX is a robust, high-performance **XML** database engine"* (quoting first line of the [BaseX home page](http://basex.org/)).

Comment: yes, @Jesse  that's the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting documentation for [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#CREATE_DB):

> **Syntax** `CREATE DB [name] ([input])`
>
> The input can be a file or directory path to **XML documents**, a remote URL, or a string containing XML

As you can see, the command expects an XML file, not a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work:

```
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size  Input Path                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
w3school_data        1          5209  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

2 database(s).
> 
> exit
See you.
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ ls
createDB.xquery  formatted.json  raw.json
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ cat createDB.xquery 
let $database := "db"
for $name in file:list('.', false(), '*.json')
let $file := file:read-text($name)
let $json := json:parse($file)
return db:add($database, $json, $name) 
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ basex createDB.xquery 
Stopped at /home/thufir/json/createDB.xquery, 5/14:
[db:open] Database 'db' was not found.
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> create database db
Database 'db' created in 269.32 ms.
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size  Input Path                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
db                   0          4570                                           
w3school_data        1          5209  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

3 database(s).
> 
> exit
See you.
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ basex createDB.xquery 
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size    Input Path                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
db                   2          196469                                           
w3school_data        1          5209    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

3 database(s).
> 
>
```

and that query will return a very large document, too large to paste here.

Just looking to do the above with Java.  The point about JSON versus XML was on point.  (The `xquery` file is [from](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/JSON_Module) the docs.)

Provided just the formatted `JSON` is in the directory, seems to work better:

```
thufir@dur:~/json$ 
thufir@dur:~/json$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size    Input Path                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
db                   1          101838                                           
w3school_data        1          5209    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

3 database(s).
> 
> open db
Database 'db' was opened in 66.85 ms.
> 
> xquery /
```

and then returns the expected result (the `JSON` in full).